# Does the knowledge of a material's atomic structure provide sufficient data to predict its behavior with matter?

Tags: particle-physics, physical-chemistry, matter, electrochemistry

What are the properties of a material on an atomic point of view that define its behavior?

The whole world around us consists of atoms of varying numbers of electrons, protons and neutrons. 
Suppose that i give a material to you **without** saying that it is called iron or plutonium or caesium etc. but  i would instead provide you with any information about its structure.

Is this enough evidence to deduce what its boiling point is, with what elements it reacts, how it conducts heat, how sound waves propagate in it, what are its equilibrium states and chemical kinetics *etc*. ?

Basically, which is the **minimum** amount of additional information that should be provided?

Comment: Materials demonstrate **lots** of behaviour,  as there are lots different physical situations, and we are still discovering the ways in which multi element compounds behave.  But for elements, the atomic structure, compared to other elements, will give you a decent idea . But this, imo,  is a list type question, which is off topic.

Comment: If you specify the atomic number of each element and which phase/structure it is in then one could, in principle, compute all of the properties you listed and more. In fact, we pretty much do this whenever we perform an ab initio calculation (e.g. [DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_functional_theory)).